# How to unit test that a set of methods must be called within the same TransactionScope using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am using MOQ for unit testing in my .Net application. I need to write unit test for ensuring that a set methods must be called with in a transaction scope. My code looks something like this:

```
using (var scope = _transactionManager.CreateScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
                Repository.MethodA();
                Repository.MethodB();
                Repository.MethodC();
                _transactionManager.CompleteScope(scope);
        }
```

I need to ensure that MethodA(), MethodB() and MethodC() of the Repository must be called inside the same TransactionScope.

Simply calling Verify to these methods in my unit test is not sufficient as that doesn't ensure that methods are called inside the same transactionscope.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at this answer and see if it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/628219/1720077

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can mock Transaction as well, possibly I may not be able understand your constraints . However you can use Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation in executing Methods to confirm. Hope it helps.